# Parsing the "types" of JSON file

Tags: android, json

It was going good until I needed to parse the type of the place, the file is organized like this:

```
        "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 45.7849210,
           "lng" : 11.8724490
        },
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 45.81619110,
              "lng" : 11.89575470
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 45.75432980,
              "lng" : 11.84532520
           }
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
     "id" : "a454072e2ba71d4e2331e39099261f086cd11d1e",
     "name" : "Fonte",
     "reference" : "CnRtAAAAUaGSsbXRv05lApqXueEKjOAjtkpEDz07ioe3vPS9HqpOIJSTTQWYObc6o6GfEq-pzVUtKT03oRWNx6ld-rUfdat47e8W3NbSsLY1NldO9iQEUjQOM9kIIOix8xLAvqh5YHUNTAela4Mo8HGSJPPBhhIQ9j4Uy_WrQtFO7qxirA0UHRoUsmY0ngstG5BBiHQNLkLgxTpsDEY",
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ],
     "vicinity" : "Fonte"
  },
```

As it is possible to notice that types is an string array I tried this approach:

```
  JSONArray results = o.getJSONArray("results");
  JSONObject tempObject = results.getJSONObject(0);
  JSONArray typee = tempObject.getJSONArray("types");
  String a = typee.getJSONObject(0).toString();
```

but it doesn't work.Any help will be appreciated.The whole JSON can be seen here: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=45.7909,11.8700&radius=500&key=AIzaSyC9Ob9_u-2mxCHeItDHytDLmZP-P1QCejw&sensor=true.

Comment: I have ListView which will display places by name, the first "type" in the types array and some other members.It was working good until I tried to add the type, and now the ListView displays nothing.But the Appliaction doesn't crash.

Comment: Then your problem is somewhere with your `ListAdapter`.

Comment: How can I find out, if Eclipse is not giving any problem and/or warning?

Comment: The same way you debug anything else. You examine your `ListAdapter`, set breakpoints in your debugger, log information to LogCat, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONArray typee = tempObject.getJSONArray("types");
String a = typee.getString(0);
String b = typee.getString(1);
```

The above will return `locality` to variable `a` and `political` to variable `b`. Use `typee.length()` to find out how many elements are in the `JSONArray` if it's possible that `types` might have a variable number of elements.